# Is it ok, that translation of “Apology of Socrates” has a lot of grammatical mistakes?

Tags: plato, socrates

This is a technical and pretty specifically question: I bought a book, that contains Apology of Socrates, and some dialogues (Kriton, Meneksen, Ion, etc) in Russian language ISBN 978-197-4015-03-0, but it has a lot of grammatical mistakes: some words are concatenated together (like: hesaid), some words instead are split (like: ta ke), wrong letters (like: teble instead of table), etc.

Is it how it should be, or is it a bad translation? Does English or other languages translations have that mistakes? I can’t find any notation about such mistakes in Platos text, so asking here.

---

As user defaultlocale pointed in comments, it seems, that I have [Soloviev's translation](http://psylib.org.ua/books/plato01/01apols.htm).

In link defaultlocale provided there is only Apology of Socrates, however in my book there are also dialogs with Kriton, Ion and others, and it seems that they have more mistakes (maybe I will add more rough, later).

For example, from the beginning of Ion dialog:

1. Letters of words, that starts the sentence are not capitalized:

***Сокр.*** *Ну что? состязался? каково совершил подвиг?*

2. On the second page, in the first footnote, two words are concatenated (although those words directly in the text are not):

*1 Такособенно* instead of *1 Так особенно*

---

**Important note**

Often text has wrong conjugation and similar grammatical mistakes, at the same time, considering Ion dialog, Ion talks about himself in the plural, and it is not mistake, but, as Plato points, it is just Ions vanity, as pointed in footnote.

Also, as in footnotes pointed, Plato sometimes used some irregular grammatical constructions.

So, that's why I am asking is it just bad translation or this is how it should be?

Comment: Are you talking about the mistakes in the Russian translation or does this book include the original Greek? Can you give us any specific examples? Anyway, the apology is available online in [Greek](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0169%3Atext%3DApol.%3Asection%3D17b), [English](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/1656/1656-h/1656-h.htm) and [Russian](http://psylib.org.ua/books/plato01/01apols.htm) and I don't see any obvious issues with any of those versions.

Comment: @defaultlocale, it seems that Russian translation You provided is what I have (I can tell for sure soon today). For example, for some reason there are “c” letters put just somewhere between words, where “c” should not be

Comment: @defaultlocale, for example “так недорого берет за **с** обучение”, if You understand Russian

Comment: Possibly it was scanned from a printed text and the character recognition introduced errors.

Comment: @Bumble I had more sad doubt, that it was kinda Google translated. It often is pretty hard and weird to read, even when there are no grammatical errors.